# How to calculate the Apache FOP page number

Tags: apache-fop

I'm working on a PFD drawing OMR function that use the page number of apache-fop for computation, but when I assign the page number retrieved from the  tag to the < XSL :variable> tag , I get not a number, but a DOM node, because I want to compute the page number by embedding it in Java,could you give me some hints?

[image: code]

```
<xsl:variable name="number">
  <fo:page-number/>
<xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="java:XslFunctions.calculate($number)"
```

Comment: You cannot use page numbers in functions or as variables, they are not resolved during XSLT, they are only resolved during the composition process (post XSLT) when FO is being made into output. Look here for what you can do: https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/2015/02/18/getting-an-area-tree-within-your-xslt-transform/

Comment: @Kevin Brown thank you very much,then I also want to ask you if there exits other method to reference the page number and use to calculate

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but i give an answer for others that can be found it useful. There is a property built-in that can be used. Below you can find an example of working code where the page number is added in the pages footer:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm" margin-top="1cm"
                margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
                <fo:region-body />

                <fo:region-after region-name="footer" />

            </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4" initial-page-number="1" id="end">

            <fo:static-content flow-name="footer" font-size="7pt">

                <fo:block>
                    Page: <fo:page-number/>/<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="end"/>
                </fo:block>
                
            </fo:static-content>


            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
               .......
               .......
            </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Important the identifier specified in `fo:page-number-citation-last` --> **'ref-id="end"'** must be equals to **id="end"** specified in the `fo:page-sequence`